# Spark - hiding errors by nulling values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can anyone explain why it makes sense for spark to do this?

```
>>> df.filter('COLUMN_A is null').show()
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+
|   COLUMN_A|        COLUMN_B|             COLUMN_C|     COLUMN_D|
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
|       null|            null|                 null|         null|
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+
only showing top 20 rows
>>> df.filter('COLUMN_A is null').count()
0
```

I think it's getting errors when parsing some rows (there are no null rows in the data files, which are csv), but it's 'nulling' the row instead of failing, and also hiding the errors from some functions like count().

Funny enough, if I write the df to disk (like with a checkpoint), then the nulls will show up.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark in order to get all the null values of a particular column you need to use

**`from pyspark.sql import functions as F`**

**`df = df.filter(F.col("col").isNull())`**

Post that you can use count() in order to get the count of that dataframe

**`df.count()`**

Comment: The problem is there are no null values in the data set.